# Use v-if with data loaded after compute?

Tags: vue.js

I have to hide a component based on data that is loaded in mounted.
BUT as far as I understand I can use only computed section for v-if which makes me unable to avoid an error that data is not ready (which is true because computed is called before mounted).

```
<v-expansion-panel v-if="shouldHide">
```

Here is computed section which I use in v-if

```
computed:
  shouldHide: function () {
    return this.data !== null; // this.data is loaded AFTER computed
}
```

Here I get the data, but this is happening AFTER computed

```
mounted: 
 getData() {
    this.data = response.data;
 }
```

Comment: You don't need a computed in a v-if, but also, it shouldn't matter if `this.data` is initialized as null then either way you do it v-if will be false until after mounted.  when you say you get an error, what is the exact error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

In vue, we need to defined data section in your component like this:

```
data(){
 return {
   Your data...
 }
}
```